# jquery slider change background position

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, uislider

I'm struggling to set and change a background image position using jquery slider.

My slider's working pretty well with the following code:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            value:5,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });  
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );    
});
```

However, I now want to change the background position of an image. I have added this code:

```
$(".beer_slider").css("background-position").val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

But nothing really happens!

Someone pointed out I should include the following variables:

```
var beer_slider = {
        "0": "-200px",
        "1": "-190px",
        "2": "-180px",
        "2": "-170px",
        "3": "-160px",
        "4": "-150px",
        "5": "-140px",
        "6": "-130px",
        "7": "-120px",
        "8": "-110x",
        "9": "-100x",
        "10": "-90x",
    };
```

But I'm not sure how to call that.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do

```
$(".beer_slider").css("background-position").val( $( "#slider" ).slider(beer_slider) );
```

?

Comment: Cheers. not working though :( Need to get this beer slider going!